# Reuse Existing Object in Django Rest Framework Nested Serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

How do I go about re-using the referenced object when using nested Serializers in the drf:

Let's say I have the following two `Model`s:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    address_line = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
```

with `Serializer`s:

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
```

Right now the Serializers handle creating both the `Address` and the `Person` together. e.g, when I post the following:

```
{
    'name': 'Alex',
    'address': {
        'address_line': "1 Here"
    }
}
```

a `Person` is created and an `Address` is created with the `Person` pointing to the newly created `Address`.

What is the best way to NOT create a new `Address` but to reuse an existing `Address` if there is already an `Address` with a given `address_line`? i.e if I wanted to make the `address_line` field `unique`? (this object re-use is sometimes called "interning")

What about if there were two address fields `address_line1` and `address_line2` and I wanted to reuse the `Address` object if there already exists an `Address` with both of those fields (i.e. `unique_together=(address_line1, address_line2)`)?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Recently I faced a similar problem, solved it using the following approach (the code has not been tested, its just for reference):

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Person

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # pop the validated user data
        # assuming its a required field,
        # it will always be there in validated_data
        address = validated_data.pop('address')

        try:
            address = Address.objects.get(address_line=address.get('address_line'))
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            address_serializer = AddressSerializer(data=address)
            address_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            address = address_serializer.save()
        else:
            # save the user and update the validated_data for setting up profile
            validated_data['address'] = address

        return super(PersonSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I had the same problem and could solve it by combining your answer **and** removing the UniqueValidator on a field in the nested serializer (https://medium.com/django-rest-framework/dealing-with-unique-constraints-in-nested-serializers-dade33b831d9), otherwise DRF threw the error *[parent object type] with this [some field] already exists.*.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overwriting the `create` method in the parent serializer (as suggested by Ankit Popli) of the unique-field-serializer, I found that the code might be simpler by overwriting the `create` method of the serializer which contains the unique field:

`models.py`

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    # more fields...

    tag = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag

    
class Scenery(models.Model):
    # more fields...

    tags = models.ManyToManyField(to=Tag, related_name='tagged_sceneries', blank=True)
```

`serializers.py`

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from drf_writable_nested.serializers import WritableNestedModelSerializer
from drf_writable_nested.mixins import UniqueFieldsMixin
from .models import Tag, Scenery

class TagSerializer(UniqueFieldsMixin, ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ['tag']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            # if there is already an instance in the database with the
            # given value (e.g. tag='apple'), we simply return this instance
            return Tag.objects.get(tag=validated_data['tag'])
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            # else, we create a new tag with the given value
            return super(TagSerializer, self).create(validated_data)


class ScenerySerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    # Many to many + unique
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Scenery
        fields = [
            'tags',
            # ... more fields
        ]
```

Comment: Although this requires the package `drf-writable-nested` this should *definitely* be the correct answer. With this I did a huge amount of work effortlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by writing custom function based validation for username field in UserSerializer which is then nested in my OrderSerializer:

```
def validate_username(self, username):
    if len(username) < 5 or len(username) > 30:
        raise ValidationError('Username must be between 5 to  30  characters long')
    if username.isdigit():
        raise ValidationError('This username is entirely numeric')
    if User.objects.filter(username__iexact=username).exists():
        raise ValidationError('This username already exists!')
    return username
```